# Flurry Timed Events tracking multiple of them

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

As per Flurry Documentation for timed events you can logEvent and then endTimedEvent which is great.

But my specific question is around what happens when we log multiple timed events at one time and when we call endTimedEvent which one of the open timed events gets closed.

So for Example: If my event is tracking user checkin into a restaurant and how much time does an average guest spends in a restaurant. So my event name would be let's say UserCheckIn. Now multiple users checkin into the restaurant which mean I have multiple timedEvents open and let say one of the guest departs I would close timedEvent.

So does Flurry takes care of this scenario? How would it tie up an open timed even to a closed timed event? Or do I need to do something special in my code.